# static object inside template class

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I have been asked several times about the uses of static object and I guess I understand the crux behind using them, but one particular case confusing me, I know that in the code they are trying to make a factorial like mechanism using recursive call but did not able to understand different stages the code will go through.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

template<short N> class C
{
  private:
     static C<N-1>c;
  public:
     static int const n = N*c.n;
};

template<> class C<0>
{
    public: 
    static int const n =1;
};

int main()
{
    cout<<C<5>::n<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

See the live demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/322ba03ed1d38548) please.

This code is generating an output `120`.

What exactly is happening here?

Comment: `static C<N-1>c;` would not be required with `static const int n = N * C<N -
 1>::n;`.

Comment: What you calculate is basically `5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1`.

Comment: ^^ Also called _factorial_ (math op is `N!`).

Comment: *"did not able to understand different stages"*: which part is unclear for you? What do you understand?

Comment: do you understand how a recursive factorial works without templates?

Comment: Well, 5! = 120, so what is unclear? Also, this code might work at `-O2`, but probably not at `-O0`; are you having issues because of that?

Answer (score 2):

It's unfortunate that the line

```
static C<N-1>c;
```

exists at all. It obfuscates the logic a little bit.

The functionality could have been as easily implemented as:

```
template<short N> class C
{
   public:
     static int const n = N*C<N-1>::n;
};

template<> class C<0>
{
  public: 
    static int const n = 1;
};
```

which is a little bit easier to follow.

The net effect is same:

```
C<5>::n = 5*C<4>::n
C<4>::n = 4*C<3>::n
C<3>::n = 3*C<2>::n
C<2>::n = 2*C<1>::n
C<1>::n = 1*C<0>::n
C<0>::n = 1
```

Now you can follow how the program produces the output.

Comment: I think it's more unfortunate that a `constexpr` function wasn't used instead [`like so`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MCyDUiEMBSFgKJZG)

Comment: @AndyG, if the OP can use a C++14 compiler, they should definitely do that.

Comment: @RSahu Even in C++11, factorial is easy enough to implement `constexpr` using recursion. I think this is sample code for understanding templates, though, not code to be used (the right tool for actually calculating a factorial is a lookup table with 21 entries, even when returning a `uint64_t`).

Comment: @DanielH, I might be mistaken but my understanding is that the code posted by AndyG is not legal in C++11. A `constexpr` function in C++11 needs to contain a simple return statement, not anything more.

Comment: @RSahu: I think what Daniel is saying is that you can achieve it by calling your `constexpr` function recursively. Edit: [demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YR4w1IsFxV0gq1lf)

Comment: @AndyG, Thanks for showing how it can be done in C++11.

Comment: @RSahu Yes, that’s exactly what I meant. I didn’t mean AndyG’s code in particular would work; I meant that you could write something that would. For some reason, factorial has become the textbook example of recursion, which was pretty much the only means of doing anything complicated in C++11 constexpr functions.